# Default value for "inc" when a new document is created on upsert using MongoDB from Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm using MongoDB 4.2 and I'd like to conditionally upsert a document in MongoDB with a default value. Here's what I have today (1):

```
collection.updateOne(
    and(eq("_id", "John Doe"), eq("version", 0L)), 
    inc("version", 1L), 
    new UpdateOptions().upsert(true)
);
```

This generates a document like this:

```
{
  "_id" : "John Doe",
  "version" : NumberLong(1)
}
```

But what I want to do is to modify (1) to have a default value of `NumberLong(10)` instead of `0` like this:

```
{
  "_id" : "John Doe",
  "version" : NumberLong(10)
}
```

I've tried doing this:

```
collection.updateOne(
    and(eq("_id", "John Doe"), eq("version", 0L)), 
    combine(inc("version", 1L), setOnInsert("version", 10L))
    new UpdateOptions().upsert(true)
);
```

but this fails with:

```
com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: Updating the path 'version' would create a conflict at 'version'

    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1015)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeUpdate(MongoCollectionImpl.java:992)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:589)
```

Is it possible to achieve this in a single call to MongoDB?

Comment: Have you tried using the `$setOnInsert` option?

Comment: @Joe Yes, it's even included in the last example in my question. But on consecutive updates I'd like to "version" to increase by 1 so I cannot only use "$setOnInsert".

Comment: `$setOnInsert` should be part of the `UpdateOptions` not part of the update, and it needs to start with the `$`.  On subsequent runs, if there is a matching document, `$setOnInsert` will not have any effect.

Comment: Your first note that _"This generates a document like this:."_  `{...,"version" : NumberLong(0) }`. Your finding is not correct. When a new document is inserted with `$inc: { version: 1 } }`, the value of the `version` will be `1`, _not_ `0` as you had mentioned. Using Java driver 3.12 and MongoDB v4.2 this works fine. See [$inc's behavior on insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/index.html#behavior).

Comment: @prasad_ you're actually right. I'll modify my question.

Comment: @Joe I cannot seem to find a way to specify `$setOnInsert` on UpdateOptions in the Java API.

Comment: for the java driver, see: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/model/Updates.html#setOnInsert-java.lang.String-TItem-